# Android: Sorting a list of names in an arrayList and linking them to the appropriate ID

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following SQL queries in my dbHelper class:

```
public ArrayList getAllStudents()
{
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+ TABLE_STUDENTS, null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)) + " , " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME))); //+ ", " +ST_FIRST_NAME )));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
public ArrayList getAllStudentIds()
{
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery( "select * from "+ TABLE_STUDENTS, null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_ID)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

One is returning the student name and surname for display in a listView while the other is accessing and returning the ID of that student so that when the user clicks on a link, it directs them to the correct student profile.

I know that the best way to do this is to use a custom adapter, but i couldn't get it to work, and do not have time to give the code an overhaul (As i have a demonstration to give on this project in 30hours time)

I have the following in my studentList class:

```
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllStudents();
    Log.d("array size:,", String.valueOf(array_list.size()));
    final ArrayList id_list = mydb.getAllStudentIds();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
    //Adding the contacts to the list view.
    student = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    student.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //Setting an onClickListener to process the user's actions
    student.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            int id_To_Search = Integer.valueOf((String)id_list.get(arg2));
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("studentId", id_To_Search);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.StudentProfilePage.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I was trying to sort the list using:

```
Collections.sort(array_list);
```

And it does exactly what i need it to do - returns the student names in alphabetical order

But i need a way to link the ID that is attached to that student profile.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `Student` class, or similar structure to represent a student?

Comment: Get the list already sorted from the database: use ORDER BY in your query.

Comment: I still suggest you to use Custom Adapter.  Its not take to much time as you have 30 hours still left.

Comment: Create a Student Pojo class. Put studentId, firstName and lastName as fields of that class create List of your Student Pojo Class and pass it to Custom Adapter.

Comment: I've tried to use a custom adapter, and it did not work. I have other stuff I still need to finish, a presentation to write etc. The last custom adapter took me two days to get my head around and NEVER worked so I really don't have time to restart all that again

Comment: Okay. All the best...!

Comment: But thank you anyway, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `public ArrayList getAllStudentIds()` method from dbHelper Class (Not required) and change your `public ArrayList getAllStudents()` like,

   ```
   public HashMap<String, String> getAllStudents()
   {
     Map<String, String> mapStudent = new HashMap<String, String>();
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+ TABLE_STUDENTS, null );
     res.moveToFirst();
     while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
     {
       mapStudent.put(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_ID)) ,res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)) + " , " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME))); //+ ", " +ST_FIRST_NAME )));
       res.moveToNext();
    }
    return mapStudent;
   }
   ```

   **So now method will return a HashMap with Student Id as Key and Student name as Value.**
2. Now your code in **`StudentList`** class, looks like,

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> studentMap = mydb.getAllStudents();
   // Converting HashMap values into ArrayList
   List<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>(studentMap.values());
   Log.d("array size:,", String.valueOf(array_list.size()));

   ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
   //Adding the contacts to the list view.
   student = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   student.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
   //Setting an onClickListener to process the user's actions
   student.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     Log.d("arg2 ", String.valueOf(arg2)); 

     TextView tempTextView = (TextView) arg1;
     String data = tempTetxtView.getText();


     for (Entry<String, String> entry : studentNameAndId.entrySet()) { 
         if (entry.getValue().equals(data)) { 
           int id_To_Search = Integer.valueOf(entry.getKey()); 
           //id_list.get(arg2+1); 
           Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle(); 
           dataBundle.putInt("studentId", id_To_Search); 
           //Create a new intent to open the DisplayContact activity 
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.StudentProfilePage.class); 
           intent.putExtras(dataBundle); 
           startActivity(intent); 
          } 
        }
       }
    });
   ```

Comment: Hey, I've tried implementing all that, but my arg2 is coming back as a null int? I've checked what the dbHelper is returning, and it is bringing back each of the IDs correctly, but they seem to be getting lost somewhere along the lines... any ideas as to why? Thanks.... Could it be something to do with my program only letting me use .values instead on .valuseSet() in the List creation?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the debugger is saying it's a null int, but a log.d output and adding breakpoints shows that it's being returned as '0' every time

Comment: I'm using a `Collections.sort(array_list)`. and the key seems to be disappearing there... should i be using something else, like an order by?

Comment: Hmm, tried that there, nothing, it's still returning 0

Answer (score 0):

Before you sort your names, loop through the two lists together and put the name as the key in a `HashMap`, with the id as the value. Then you can find the ID from the Name. Order your two SQL statements by the same columns to make sure the two lists represent students in the same order.

But of course if you have two students with the same name, you won't be able to distinguish. Really having one method connecting to the database (since you already do `SELECT *`) returning BOTH the ID and the name would be much better. I'd encourage you to do that, your code will be much cleaner and bug-free.

Comment: I've never used a HashMap before, and have No idea how to use one! I've tried using just the one method to return an Id and a name, but the return statement does not let me return two separate lists, and as the name is being used for the list display I can't return the I'd in the same arraylist

Comment: A hashmap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) associate keys with values, a bit like a database table with a primary key. A HashMap is one of the fundamental data structure you need to know about when programming!

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look. I'm just finishing up a software degree and haven't been taught about them

Comment: @JPMoresmau I'd generalize that to `Map` is a fundamental data structure you need to know about. `HashMap` is the implementation of `Map` which is most often used. Likewise `List` is the fundamental data structure, and `ArrayList` is a commonly-used implementation.

Comment: @ShWhite `I'm just finishing up a software degree and haven't been taught about them` - if that's true, you should probably get a tuition refund. Data structures like `List`, `Map`, and `Set` are vital to software development and you needed to learn about them by your 2nd year of university.

Comment: @MartinCarney - Is a hashmap similar to a data dictionary? I'm from the UK and we've been taught different stuff...?

Comment: @ShWhite In Java, `HashMap` is an implementation of the `Map` interface, and it uses the key's `getHash()` method to store the value in a hash table for fast lookup. In terms of data structures regardless of language, a map and a dictionary are the same thing. If you've been taught about "dictionaries" instead of "maps", then you're fine, you just needed to know they're the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sort the data once (or once per database access), use the database to sort your data. Something like `SELECT * FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_last_name` would do the trick.

But, you also have some other areas that need work. Create a `Student` class with, for example, `firstName`, `lastName`, and `id` fields. Instead of managing multiple lists, just have one `List<Student>`, with each `Student` object containing the student's name *and* id.

You can have the database sort them for you, or you can set up `Students` for Java sorting. Add `implements Comparable<Student>` to your Student class, and implement `public int compareTo(Student s) { ... }`. `compareTo()` should return a negative number if `this` comes before `s`, a positive number if `s` comes before `this`, or 0 if they are the same. I'd implement it like this:

```
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    int result = this.lastName.compareTo(s.lastName);
    if (result == 0) {
        result = this.firstName.compareTo(s.firstName);
    }
    if (result == 0) {
        result = this.id - s.id;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This would sort by last name, then first name, then id (and it takes advantage of String's existing `compareTo(String)` implementation to save yourself a lot of work).